# Why does this (old) funding proposal for MathOverflow, say that Ben Green got the Fields Medal?

Tags: discussion

[This funding proposal](https://web.archive.org/web/20200725221303/https%3A%2F%2Ftqft.net%2Fweb%2Fservice%2FMathOverflow%2FSloan%2Fproposal.pdf) says:

[image]

But [Ben's name is not mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal).

Comment: I've already got a downvote. It's my first time ever here, should I ask in the chat room instead of here?

Comment: It's a fine question but this is _really_ old and it might be an old draft. I'd have to check our records and compare with the proposal we actually sent. How did you find this?

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais I was doing some research, and this PDF showed up in a Google search! I recognized the name Ben Green because I'm an Oxonian and one of my former students (Albert Wood) did his 4th year research project with Ben. When I saw his name in the proposal I reacted "wow Ben got the Fields medal recently? how did I miss that!"

Comment: Well, I can confirm that Ben Green won many highly prestigious awards but not a Fields medal at this time. We might have corrected this error in the proposal we submitted to the Sloan Foundation nearly a decade ago, I'm not sure (and it's not worth looking up unless you _really_ want to know). I'm sure we would have appreciated the correction at the time but we probably would have responded editing "Fields medalist" to a more encompassing and accurate description of our highest profile users.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Thanks. So basically my understanding is that it was a typo (most likely corrected in a later version). The final proposal would be interesting, since I'm doing something similar for the new [Matter Modeling](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) community that I started and very recently entered Beta on SE. But I've already picked up some good ideas from the PDF version that I linked in my question, and I don't want to ask you to spend unnecessary time finding a different version that's probably not much different.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais Since that funding proposal was old, I wonder if you know of any other Fields Medalists you could add [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Notable_Scientists_and_Mathematicians)?  I have already added Ed Witten.

Comment: Peter Scholze has posted a few times on MO, mostly, though not entirely, before winning the Fields Medal.

Comment: Martin Hairer is also active here. Richards Borcherds used to be, but he has not visited the site for 8 years.

Comment: There's Curtis McMullen (assuming it's the same person, which it looks like it is).

Comment: I've added my downvote to this question. This old little error is not worth an inquiry, nor publicity.

Comment: @MaoWao Do you know whether [Michael Freedman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/58457/michael-freedman) or [Michael Freedman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/122296/michael-freedman) is [Michael Freedman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Freedman)?

Comment: Apart from Freedman, I've checked all Fields medalists from 1982 or later and didn't find any more (but only checked their full names and then only last names). I'll check the rest later. Seems we got all the recent ones, at least.

Comment: @user1271772 It seems quite likely that the first Michael Freedman is the fields medalist (but I don't have any privileged knowledge here).

Comment: The link to the proposal is dead (error 404). Is it because of this question? Where can we see the proposal?

Comment: @Taladris I've updated it to WayBackMachine now. It would have been nice if when Scott Morrison removed it, he notified us here.

Answer (score 10):

Presumably just a minor editing error — either a typo or a thinko.

Frankly, it seems a little odd to ask about this.  As pointed out in comments, this pdf is an early draft of a ten-year-old funding proposal, so there’s nothing notable about finding minor errors in it; the only surprising thing is that this pdf is still online and discoverable.

Comment: However, giving a Field's medal to someone who didn't actually get one, is not a "minor" error.

Comment: @user1271772 It would not be a minor error for the IMU to make. For anyone else, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @user1271772: Context is key. If a mathematician erroneously claimed a Fields Medal on their own CV or website, that would be a very serious error. If MO is listing affiliated Fields Medallists as one among many supporting elements of a funding proposal, that’s not so big, though certainly worth pointing out and correcting. But since the error is in a *draft version* of that *ten year old* proposal, it seems of very little significance at all.